# Прописные буквы

Tags: прописная-строчная

Здравствуйте. Вопрос о прописных буквах. Как правильно:
1). Служил в Московской думе.
2). Служил в городской думе
3). Был избран в Думу
4). Органами городской власти были Думы и управы
5). Вошёл в думский особняк
6). Поблизости возвели здание Думы
7). Со временем Боярские думы… 
Какими правилами пользоваться в таких предложениях? 
И ещё подобный вопрос: 
Как правильно: Российская Империя или  Российская империя? 
Спасибо. Валентина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о названии учреждения, то с большой буквы пишется только первое слово.
Примеры: *Русский музей, Институт мозга*.
Однако "Государственная Дума" пишется с большой буквы оба слова - согласно Конституции РФ. Но прилагательное, образованное от слова Дума, пишется с маленькой - "думский".
Что же касается империи, что это словосочетание подчиняется первому правилу: Российская империя. Но при этом пишется Российская Федерация, поскольку тут оба слова - название страны.